# Spring expression cannot resolve type

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-el

I have a service method annotated with `@PostAuthorize`

```
@PostAuthorize("hasPermission(returnObject, new ReadUserPermission())")
public Optional<User> find(String email) {
    // implementation
}
```

As soon as the method gets called, spring throws the following exceptions:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1003E:(pos 28): A problem occurred whilst attempting to construct an object of type 'ReadUserPermission' using arguments '()'
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.ConstructorReference.findExecutorForConstructor(ConstructorReference.java:190) ~[spring-expression-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.ConstructorReference.createNewInstance(ConstructorReference.java:151) ~[spring-expression-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.ConstructorReference.getValueInternal(ConstructorReference.java:94) ~[spring-expression-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getArguments(MethodReference.java:147) ~[spring-expression-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:79) ~[spring-expression-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:113) ~[spring-expression-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:105) ~[spring-expression-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.expression.ExpressionUtils.evaluateAsBoolean(ExpressionUtils.java:11) ~[spring-security-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    ... 86 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.AccessException: Failed to resolve constructor
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveConstructorResolver.resolve(ReflectiveConstructorResolver.java:121) ~[spring-expression-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.ConstructorReference.findExecutorForConstructor(ConstructorReference.java:181) ~[spring-expression-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    ... 93 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1005E:(pos 0): Type cannot be found 'ReadUserPermission'
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.StandardTypeLocator.findType(StandardTypeLocator.java:81) ~[spring-expression-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveConstructorResolver.resolve(ReflectiveConstructorResolver.java:61) ~[spring-expression-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    ... 94 common frames omitted
```

`ReadUserPermission` looks like this:

```
@Component
public class ReadUserPermission implements Permission<User> {

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(User user, User target) {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

At first, neither the class `ReadUserPermission` nor the interface `Permission` was annotated with `@Component`. I thought maybe springs needs the annotation to find the type but it does not matter if I annotate the interface or the class or both. The exception is always the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I overlooked this part of the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-constructors):

> Constructors can be invoked using the new operator. The **fully qualified class name** should be used for all but the primitive type and String (where int, float, etc, can be used)