# How to use Kotlin's `is` operator in SpEL expression?

Tags: spring, kotlin

I have a simple sealed class

```kotlin
sealed class Target {
    class User(val id: Long) : Target()
    class City(val id: String) : Target()
}
```

that is used as a parameter of s Spring bean method. I'd like to cache the method via the `@Cacheable` conditionally only when the parameter is `User`.

```kotlin
@Cacheable(CACHE_NAME, condition = "#target is Target.User")
open fun getFeed(target: Target): Map<String, Any?> { ... }
```

However I get an error: `'(' or <operator> expected, got 'is'`

How can I use `is` in the condition string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [Raphael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64375264/5698865) I was able to find out that

1. Instead of Kotlin's `is` there's Java's `instanceof`.
2. SpEL [has a special syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7628978/5698865) for using `instanceof` where you need to use a wrapper around the class: `filterObject instanceof T(YourClass)`.
3. The [fully qualified class name must be used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25785069/5698865) for classes from any other package than `java.lang`.
4. The fully qualified name available on runtime for a class defined inside the body of a sealed class is `<package>.<SealedClass>$<SubClass>`. In my case it was `net.goout.feed.model.Target$User`.

Putting all this together yeilds this SpEL

```
#target instanceof T(net.goout.feed.model.Target$User)
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, SpEL is java-based, and Java does not have an operator called 'is'. The Java equivalent of 'is' is 'instanceof'. Since Java and Kotlin are interoperable and you can work with Kotlin classes in a Java context, `#target instanceof FeedTarget.User` should work fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer! You pointed me in the right direction however the working solution required bit more digging. See my answer. .)